# How to handled HardwareButtons.BackPressed in UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, prism

I have UWP app with Prism and AppShell.
I want add confirmation dialog before exit by BackButton.
I tried this:

```
protected override Task OnLaunchApplicationAsync(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        ...
        SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += App_BackRequested;

        ...
    }

private void App_BackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        if (rootFrame == null)
        {  
           return;
        }

        if (rootFrame.CanGoBack && e.Handled == false)
        {
            <add confirm dialog here>
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

But rootFrame always is null and if history stack empty and I pressed BackButton app is close even if imake this:

```
private void App_BackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
{
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

Also I tried

```
HardwareButtons.BackPressed += App_BackRequested;
```

and it not help too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add these below lines to **`OnLaunchApplicationAsync`** method

```
protected override Task OnLaunchApplicationAsync(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        //......
        DeviceGestureService.GoBackRequested += (s, e) =>
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            e.Cancel = true;
            if (NavigationService.CanGoBack())
            {
                NavigationService.GoBack();
            }
            else
            {
                // PUT YOUR LOGIC HERE (Confirmation dialog before exit)
                Application.Current.Exit();
            }
        };
        //......
     }
```

Comment: +1. If you explain what you achieve by this it is easier for the PO to understand how you address the problem.

Comment: using Prism gives the ability to handle Hardware Buttons events like (CameraButtonReleased, CameraButtonPressed, CameraButtonHalfPressed, GoBackRequested, .....) just implement it in OnLaunchApplicationAsync method

Answer (score 4):

Add code in App.xaml.cs -

```
 private async void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
    {

        e.Handled = true;
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        if (rootFrame.CanGoBack && rootFrame != null)
        {

            rootFrame.GoBack();
        }
        else
        {
            var msg = new MessageDialog("Confirm Close");
            var okBtn = new UICommand("OK");
            var cancelBtn = new UICommand("Cancel");
            msg.Commands.Add(okBtn);
            msg.Commands.Add(cancelBtn);
            IUICommand result = await msg.ShowAsync();

            if (result != null && result.Label == "OK")
            {
                Application.Current.Exit();
            }
        }
    }
```

Add this line in constructor of App.xaml.cs -

```
HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
```

Comment: It work on new blank project, but not work in my app. 
 rootFrame always null and if I press NO on popup app closed anyway. I think it because I have this:

            protected override UIElement CreateShell(Frame rootFrame)
        {
            var shell = Container.Resolve<AppShell>();
            shell.SetContentFrame(rootFrame);
            return shell;
        }